# Создание xml файла фиксированного размера

Tags: c#

Есть массив данных из них нужно сделать xml файлы по N mb.

1. Делать XElement приводить к строке и получать количество байт не очень хорошо, ToString создаст очень много лишних строк.
2. Другой вариант делать поток и получать с него количество байт. 
   Какие у кого идеи есть?

Comment: А структура заранее известна? Может измерять не мегабайтами, а количеством элементов? По байтам ровно всё равно ведь не порезать...

Comment: Структура известна. Да можно оценить по сущности. Спасибо за идею.  @АндрейNOP

Comment: Точно порезать не удастся (понятно, почему?). Прагматически: измерьте, сколько места занимает один элемент по максимуму, а также расходы на открывающие/закрывающие теги. Решите линейное уравнение, получите примерное количество элементов в пачке.